# Traefik enable sticky-sessions on existing cookie

Tags: docker, traefik, sticky-session

I'm used to using Traefik, Docker, and K8S in a stateless environment.
Recently I was assigned the mission to Dockerize an old Java app running on Tomcat.
This app is stateful and doesn't share sessions, for now.

I have to put multiple instances of this app behind a reverse proxy that supports sticky sessions.
I successfully implemented it with Traefik, but I want to go a step forward.

For now, Traefik has its own sticky-cookie. But it kinds of make a duplicate with the already existing `JSESSIONID` set by Tomcat at the first request. Plus, the front is public and doesn't need sticky sessions, it is only needed when a user logs in.

I tried to set the label `'traefik.http.services.whoami-instance.loadBalancer.sticky.cookie.name=JSESSIONID'` but it breaks the sticky-session, and it goes back to some kind of roundrobin.

What I want to know is, is there a way to force Traefik to roundrobin when a specific cookie doesn't exist, say `JSESSIONID`, and when the backend servers set that cookie, Traefik switches to sticky-session and forwards the requests to the same server ?

As always, thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents of the cookies are vastly different and they are not interchangeable.

A traefik cookie contains the url of the internal container eg. `http://10.0.2.153:8080` whereas JSESSIONID contains an id value eg. `DC57ABB53F4DE0BDCE7EE6FEFDFDFA97`

Since traefik uses the content of the cookie to do routing, it is not possible to use another cookie that does not contain that information.

Comment: I also wondered how Traefik stored the map, and you answered both of my questions at once. Thanks